# VBA EXCEL Replace whole string if text found in it?

Tags: excel, vba

how can i resovlve the follwing issue in VBA

if string contains "SeachText" replace whole string.

ex.

```
input:        "Test_1_The_Text_SeachString_Sth" 
input:        "Test_2_The_Text_SeachString_Sth" 
look for:     "SeachrString"
replace with  "New_Text"
```

so after execute the code the

`"Test_1_Of_The_Text_SeachString_Sth"` will become `"New_Text"`

as well as:

`"Test_2_Of_The_Text_SeachString_Sth"` will become `"New_Text"`

Answer (score 2):

Use Instr function like this:

```
  ip1= "Test_1_The_Text_SeachString_Sth" 
  lookfor="SeachString"

  If instr(ip1,lookfor)>0 then
     ip1= "newtext"
  End if
```

Comment: + 1 :) Also it would be worth while to explain about `vbTextCompare` :)